# Can the primary key referenced by a foreign key be a varchar(255) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I've run this query on mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE `connections` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `connections_serial_fk`
        FOREIGN KEY (`serial`)
        REFERENCES `devices`(serial) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And I'm getting error number 150. I already looked for the documentation and the thing I think that may be causing this error is that the column 'serial' is a varchar(255).

[This reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) says "innodb permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns".

Does MySql have this restriction?

From my schema:

devices:

```
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| serial          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

connections:

```
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| serial          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Comment: Edit your question and paste your table definitions. Is there a unique constraint of any kind of devices.serial?

Comment: There, my edits. The columns are exactly the same on both tables and the other fields are pretty common. There are no other constraints of any kind.

Comment: `devices.serial` does not seem to be a primary (or unique) key.

Comment: There's only one column in each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dbms that conforms to standard SQL will prevent you from setting a foreign key reference to a column (or columns) that doesn't have some kind of unique constraint on it--either PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE. But [MySQL *does* permit this kind of nonsense](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) under certain circumstances.

> Additionally, MySQL requires that the referenced columns be indexed
>   for performance reasons. However, the system does not enforce a
>   requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT
>   NULL. The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys
>   that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as
>   UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that
>   reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys.

Foreign keys should reference only a column (or columns) that have been declared either `PRIMARY KEY` or `NOT NULL UNIQUE`. If you think you need a foreign key reference to a nonunique column or columns, that's a big red flag, waving in your face, held by a guy yelling, "You have a design problem!"

Comment: Ok! I created an Id for that table and referenced it. That went way better.

Comment: But now you're referencing an id number, which is a surrogate for the former primary key. As far as we can tell, you're *not* referencing anything to do with *serial* (whatever *serial* means). That means `on update` and `on delete` clauses probably won't do quite what you expect. (At least, they won't do what you seemed to intend in the question as originally written.) Adding an ID number rarely solves a structural problem. That's why I asked you to paste your table structures (CREATE TABLE statements) into your question.

Comment: Actually I rewrote all this with the id being the primary key. Your answer made rethink some design decisions and I changed it. Now I have id as my primary key. Thanks!

Comment: *"Now I have id as my primary key."* That might be more of a problem than a solution. You can reference it with a foreign key, because it's backed by an index. But referencing a surrogate key is not the same thing as referencing another column in the same row. I don't know how to be more clear about that. You're doing something that now appears to work, but what it's doing is different than what you started with.

Comment: I understood your comment, but I dropped the table and recreated with id being the primary key. I could restart the process, because I didn't have any records. The design problem you made me see, was that I was using 'serial' for other purposes it shouldn't be used (as a primary key, in this case).

Comment: @MauricioMoraes Did you understand that if the value of connections serial had to always be a value of devices serial then there is still that constraint to be enforced? Also, if table T serial needed to be a devices serial and now T has (id,serial) then you probably now need T (id,serial) to be a devices (id,serial). (Although if target fields can be null then they aren't FK constraints.) But if you dropped serial from T, ok.

Comment: Yes, I understand your concern. You're right. Now 'connections' only have the 'devices_id' on it. Its cleaner. Thanks!